# Frontend and backend in docker container

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a frontend in Angular and the corresponding backend in Spring Boot. Both are standalone projects.
Now after the development phase of both projects, I want to put them into production mode. And here all my questions begin.

After reading a lot of best-practices, I came to the decision, that I should host both projects in seperate docker containers. The frontend will use nginx as the webserver, and the spring boot project the  default embedded tomcat webserver.

My question: 
If I separate them, which port should be assigned to the webservers? In the future, both should only communicate with HTTPS, so both will have the same port number 443? Or should the Backend Server use the Port 8443? How should I deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a third container for reverse proxy which would redirect your incoming traffic to relevant container. This has several benefits:

1. You can use some well known images for reverse proxy which comes with useful configurations for Letsencrypt (which is free) certificate. Here's a good one you can use: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt
2. You don't need to expose your backend server's port to internet. You will only need to open your ports to your internal network. If you are running all of your containers in 1 host, you can greatly benefit from docker-compose and docker network.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have an example for such a reverse proxy?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what type of example you are asking for. But I would suggest this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spbkCihFpQ8&t=249s) to see how reverse proxy can (partially) solve your problem or answer your original question. This tutorial does not show how to set up SSL though. For that one, you need to explore the github page I have posted above.  For now, I am sure this will be a great starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use the same port number for both, then worth having Load Balancer in front of the services and based on the request, should forward the request to that service.

Or simple approach, deploy both containers on different ports (443 and 8443), that would be easy